# An exercise from Conway (Phragmen-Lindelöf Theorem)

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]
The exercise is from Chapter 6.4 Complex Analysis by Conway. I am new in this field and have no idea how to start or process. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The $a<b<1$ is to ensure that $|arg(e^{bz})| = b |Im(z)|$ stays $\le b \pi/2$ so that $e^{A e^{Re(z)}}e^{−\epsilon e^{bz}}\to 0$ when $Re(z) \to \infty$

Comment: Still, I don't understand things. I actually saw the Wikipedia before. So if you could give me more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The complete answer resides on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle#Example_of_application).